# Listen for newly opened windows with a specific title

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to bind the execution of some Python code to the opening of a window with a specific title?

I know there are some ways to list all the currently open windows, but it would be nice to not have to constantly poll.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if this is possible as well.  I do a lot of GUI automation in Python and I've dealt with this type of issue by creating threads to wait for my window - if there were a way to associate an open window event, rather than use a thread this would help me, too.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with polling done every second or so. You could generally implement the notifications mechanism yourself. Create a new thread which would poll and have a dict with {'keyword' : callback_function} that you can update. Have the thread execute a callback function when a new matching window is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyAA seems like it might be the only module that will let you do this. The tutorial for it is gone but I managed to find an archived copy of it.

[Section of tutorial covering Event Watchers](http://replay.web.archive.org/20070607225502/http://www.cs.unc.edu/~parente/tech/tr09.shtml#event_watchers)

[The module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyAA/2.0)

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [windows hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically, the WH_SHELL hook should allow you to monitor window creation.